# Why Naive Bayes is not written as $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes-classifier

I am currently learning Naive Bayes and observed that equation is given as,

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A).P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$

where, B are features and A is prediction value(yes/no)

But why not write it as,

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

I believe this formula is simple. But, why most of the sites and tutorials do not use this equation/formula? Is it correct to use this formula?

Comment: At a simplified level, Bayesian is about taking into account separately the prior probability $P(A)$ (which can be obtained from a different source than the sample in theory). Thus it is relevant for a Bayesian model to make this quantity explicit in the equation: both formulas are correct, but the one which actually shows what one needs to calculate is the first one.

Comment: @Erwan, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
is the actually $\text{Conditional Probability}$ but $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A).P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$ is not **only** actually Bayes theorem.

Bayes theorem states that let $A_1, A_2,.... A_n$ be $n$ pairwise mutually exclusive events such that **one of them certainly occurs**, i.e. $A_iA_j=\phi(i \neq j);i, j=1,2,3,4.....n$ and $A_1+ A_2+....+ A_n=S,$ the certain event and if $X$ be any event then $P(X) = P(A_1) P(X/A_1)+P(A_2) P(X/A_2)+.......+P(A_n) P(X/A_n) 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i) P(X/A_i)[\text {Total  probability}]$

If further $P(X) \neq 0,$ then Bayes theorem states that $$P(A_j|X) = \frac{P(A_j).P(X|A_j)}{P(X)}$$ which could be written as $$\frac{P(A_j \cap X)}{P(X)}[\text{Conditional Probability}]$$

Comment: But why would sites/tutorials are going for more complex equation which requires 1 multiplication and a division, instead of a simple equation which require only 1 division(Just saying, all I meant was why more complex equation).

Comment: In most of the cases first you need to apply Bayes theorem's `Total probability` then `conditional probability`. It's the rule of Bayes theorem otherwise we can't directly apply `conditional probability`.

Comment: A1, A2 .. are features? If yes then I think it should be B1, B2... and it should be multiplication I think. We can also calculate total probability as $$ P(A \cap B1)* P(A \cap B2)...$$ right?

Comment: No, they're mutually exclusive events. Please read carefully my answer. Before reading you need to understand what is event, what is random variable etc.

Comment: Taking Example, let features B1 be type of weather (Sunny,Rainy), B2 be temperature(Hot, Cold). A be I will be playing football (Yes, No). If I understand your answer correctly you meant B1 and B2 are mutually exclusive. $$P(A=yes | B1,B2) = [P(A)P(B1|A) . P(A)P(B2|A)]/[P(B1)P(B2)]$$ then, we should also able to write,  $$P(A=yes | B1,B2) = [P(A \cap B1) . P(A \cap B2)]/[P(B1)P(B2)]$$ Please let me know where am I mistaking in this equation? As B1 and B2 where mutually exclusive we where able to separate P(A|B1,B2) to P(A|B1) . P(A|B2)

Comment: No, A1, A2.... An are mutually exclusive.